# Django Date Range vs postgres fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, date-range

In Django, what is the difference between, and the use cases for,

[range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#range)

and

[daterange](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#daterangefield)

It seems like the latter only for Postgres users, so is the former for everyone else? Is that the only difference?

My specific use case is be able to take a person's date of starting and ending employment to determine if 'event' happened while they were with the company.

Comment: The one takes two dates and produces a filtering expression, the other allows the storage and manipulation of a genuine range value in your database. Do you see the fundamental difference there, and if so can you clarify your question?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I think I was confused because the daterange examples in the docs are also creating querysets. Thx. Do you want the points? You have to make it an answer...